# How to do testing in rails using rspec with factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Hi i am working on rails application with ruby 2.5.0 and rails 5. I have written an api to check user exist with provided username and token.

```
check_token_controller.rb
class CheckTokenController < ApplicationController

    def create
        begin
            user = User.where(email: check_params[:username], token: check_params[:token]).first
            if user.blank?
                render json: {},
                 status: 401
            else
                render json: {},
                 status: 200
            end
        rescue => e
            render json: {},
                 status: 500
        end
    end

    private

  def check_params
    permitted = %i[username token]
    params.require(:data)
          .require(:attributes)
          .permit(permitted)
          .transform_keys(&:underscore)
  end
end
```

now i want to test this api in my spec.rb file.

```
*spec/controllers/check_token_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe CheckTokenController do

    let(:user) { instance_double('user') }
  let(:save_result) { true }
  let(:params) do
    { data: { attributes: { fullname: 'michael febrianto',email: 'saddam@gmail.com', token: 'rWCyRUgfLODuc8B4DvA_8w',password: 'password' } } }
  end

  before do
    allow(User).to receive(:new).and_return(user)
    allow(user).to receive(:save).and_return(save_result)
  end

  let(:params) do
    { data: { attributes: { username: 'saddam@gmail.com', token: 'rWCyRUgfLODuc8B4DvA_8w' } } }
  end

  describe 'POST create' do
    subject { post :create, params: params }

    context 'when success' do
      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(200) }
    end

    context 'when failed' do
      it { is_expected.to have_http_status(401) }
    end
  end
end
```

i am first time working with rspec now whenever i run this test it doesnot create any test data i checked with debugger. please help me how can i create a test data and then i can test my api. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue? Which test is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the books:

**Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec**

**The RSpec Book: Behaviour-Driven Development**

They might help you.